# System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, restsharp

Using **IIS, ASP.NET Core 2.2 and RestSharp** V106.6.10 via Nuget on multiple servers getting exceptions after a period of time. My API calls with RestSharp work for a while then all of a sudden they start failing with common exception messages such as...

> **"ErrorException:System.Net.WebException:** An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to read data from the transport connection: **A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.IO.IOException**: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed** because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

This occurs on multiple servers and I have yet to determine the source of the issue.

I have tried to create `RestClient` per call and also as a singleton with the same exception in both cases. I have also tried using synchronously as well as async all the way from the controller to the server call. In all cases I continue to get the above failure messages after a period of time.

Restarting the apppool does not resolve the issue. The only thing that will resolve this is a server reboot. I believe it has something to do with http client connections and reaching some limit but have yet to determine why I continue to have this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (Reference also [https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1322](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1349))

Code currently looks like...

```cs
var defaultTimeout = 5 * 60 * 1000;
_restClientTimeout = defaultTimeout;
_restClientReadWriteTimeout = defaultTimeout;
_requestTimeout = defaultTimeout;
_client = new RestClient(_fastFieldBaseUrl);
_client.Timeout = _restClientTimeout;
_client.ReadWriteTimeout = _restClientReadWriteTimeout;

var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST);
request.Timeout = _requestTimeout;
request.ReadWriteTimeout = _requestTimeout;
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("body", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
try
{
    var response = await _client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
        return response.RawBytes;
    }
    else
    {
        var message= $"ExecuteTaskAsync raw bytes is null                    GetResponseMessage(response)}";
        Log(message, traceIdentifier, null, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Error);
        return null;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    var message = $"Error: {e.ToString()}";
    Log(message, traceIdentifier, e, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Error);
}
```

Comment: Does this kill the entire server? Or is the problem limited to the application that is using this RestClient? i.e. if you get to the point where RestSharp starts to time out, can you make any successful requests to the server via something like PostMan (or curl or whatever)? Or do those time out as well?

Comment: Just to clarify, the only part that threw me off is "The only thing that will resolve this is a server reboot." -> are you talking about the server you are calling here, or the server making the requests using RestClient?

Comment: Our server calls out to other API's using RestSharp.  Once it starts failing, all calls going from our server to any other via http fail.

Comment: Yes, it seems that any call from our server to any other API (server) via http fails until the reboot.

Comment: Having the same issue with .net framework project on the server now too.  Server configuration?